# Chatting between 2 PC on wifi in ROS

Tags: ros

How can I connect 2 PCs in ROS and chatting in this environment
My project is connect 2PCs in wifi and we can chatting in it. I have just completed basic tutorial of ROS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything? If you completed the tutorial then you probably know how topics and/or services work. If not, then you can read more about topics [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics).

The idea would be to use the publisher/subscriber pattern with ROS topics. One PC would publish (talk) and the other would listen for new messages on the topic.

But you need to be aware that there must be one master (roscore) running and it needs to be accessible from the other PC. You can do this by setting the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP environment variables accordingly. You can check [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) on how to do this.